# How apply masking on label using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have requirement like to show SSN(Social Security Number) value in label but when I am showing it in label it will not applying masking.I have used following line of code to mask value in lable.
$("#test").mask("00-00-0000");
In case of textbox its working fine.So please let me know how can I implement it.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) can do mask on label:

[JsFiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/refan/9xrkorkm/1/)

```
<label id="ssn">999990000</label>

$(function() {
    $("#ssn").mask("00-00-0000"); 
});
```